# glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D); Does not feel like working.... :(

Tags: java, opengl, texture2d

So, I'm trying to apply a texture to my quad.
So i wrote this line of code : (line 35 in Artist.java)

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Which gave me this error :

```
GL_TEXTURE_2D cannot be resolved to a variable
```

I have these imports : (Hitting CTRL+SHIFT+O  did not do anything)

```
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_MODELVIEW;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_PROJECTION;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_QUADS;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glBegin;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glEnd;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glLoadIdentity;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glMatrixMode;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glOrtho;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.glVertex2f;

import org.lwjgl.LWJGLException;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.DisplayMode;
```

I'm using Java, Eclipse, Mars. Anyone know why it won't work? :)

Comment: `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL_TEXTURE_2D;` maybe

Comment: It turns GL_TEXTURE_2D into a  type , but it doesn't fix the error.

Comment: Should work just like the other enums you use: `import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D) is a directive to the fixed-function
>   pipeline's shader generator that you want to include code to support
>   that texture unit

So if you use a modern opengl which has custom shaders, its option won't work ,and you won't need it.

Answer (score 0):

For it to not error you need to import both GL_TEXTURE_2D and glEnable().

Like Sung Woo mentioned however, this function is deprecated and only needs to be used in the old OpenGL.